# inArray jQuery from php array, finding the item index

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

This code, which I've found somewhere online, works fine and it's kind of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arrData = [ "j", "Q", "u", "e","r","y" ];   
    alert(jQuery.inArray("Q", arrData));
});
```

However, I have an array from a loop with php/mysql that I output and save like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM geo_orter");
            while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))){
                $i = $row['ort_id'];
                $result[$i] = $row['ortnamn'];
            };
            $allaOrterjson=json_encode($result);
```

Then I go ahead and do this, which works:

```
var allaOrter=<?php echo $allaOrterjson ?>;

    document.write(allaOrter[0] + allaOrter[1] + allaOrter[2]);
```

and gives me

> undefinedAborremålaAbbjörnahall

Here's the issue:

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(jQuery.inArray("Aborremåla", allaOrter));
});
```

but it results in "-1"   (Not found).

I'm trying to find out the index nr of an item in the array. Any ideas?

Log result:
[image: loggen]

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: ohh, I had no idea mysql_ is moving out.

Comment: `allaOrter[0]` is undefined - why is that so? Do a console.log(allaOrter) in your JavaScript and check the developer console in Chrome/Firefox etc. What does it say?

Comment: @AndersHolmström First one is undefined because there is no "ortnamn" with index 0 so the first one is empty

Comment: @anders: because JS arrays start at 0, but sql ids generally start at 1.

Comment: @Alisso I'd recommend building the JS array manually and see if the same thing happens. Just for a test, do `var allaOrter = [undefined, "Aborremåla", "Abbjörnahall"];` in the JS and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `json_encode($result);` creates a JSON **object**, not an array. Hence `jQuery.inArray` isn't working.

Build a JavaScript array instead: `[ "value", "value", "value", etc... ];`

Or do something like this with the object:

```
var locations = {
    "Abårremöla" : 1,
    "Stuff" : 2,
    "Ludvika" : 1549
};

var query = "Ludvika";
if(query in locations) {
    var id = locations[query];
    alert(id); //displays 1549
}
```

For that to work you have to build up the object the other way around in PHP - so a PHP array with the location name as the indexer and the id as the value:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ort_id, ortnamn FROM geo_orter");
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))){
    $index = $row['ortnamn'];     //<- note!
    $result[$i] = $row['ort_id']; //<- note!
};
$allaOrterjson=json_encode($result);
```

Comment: But can I then control the index of each item?

Comment: Each value has an id in the db so I'm trying to create a list with values and their ids as indexes so that I can look through it as the user chooses a value

Comment: Or is there perhaps a way to look through the object instead? :)

Comment: I understand the problem. What do you actually want to do with the object? Check if it has a certain value?

Comment: Updated my answer with an object-based solution.

Comment: I'll try this out. The user will input a city in the form, and so I want the form to send me the index of that city so that I can tag the new record with the city id instead of the city name

Comment: Alright. Then I think my solution with `if(query in locations)` *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var my_cars= new Array()
my_cars[0]="Mustang";

my_cars["family"]="Station Wagon";

my_cars["big"]="SUV";

for( var i in my_cars ){
    console.log( my_cars[i] );
}

var n = {
    "0": "Mustang",
    "family": " Station Wagon",
    "big": "SUV"
};
for( var i in n ){
    console.log( n[i] );
}
```